# command timeout through SqlHelper in asp.net 2.0

Tags: sql, asp.net, response

I have an application that works with asp.net 2.0, I want to increase command timeout but it is using sqlHelper class;

```
dsData = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connectionstring, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, m_SqlParam)
```

I can't find any example on this, or should I change SqlHelper code?

Comment: See if this link helps. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you, my application uses stored procedure and SQLHelper library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` property like below

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);    
command.CommandTimeout = 20;
```

Your `SqlHelper` looks  like a custom wrapper (or) a repository class for the `SqlCommand`. In such case, you can either change your code base in your `SqlHelper` class (OR) have your `ExecuteDataset()` method accept another argument for timeout